# Why isn't OutOfMemoryError reproduced with a Collection of Object?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm, out-of-memory

I'm trying to reproduce `OutOfMemoryError` with this code:

```
List<Object> objects = new LinkedList<>();
while (true)
    objects.add(new Object());
}
```

But it actually never happens, I used -Xmx512 and JVM just takes about 497 MB each time and then memory isn't consumed.

I use jdk1.8.0_151

Could anyone help me figure out why the error isn't thrown?

Comment: Did you really check that the second line was inside the loop-block while adding a println?

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful yes, it was

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not getting `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError` because you are creating very small objects (`new Object()`) and heap size you have specified is pretty large. If you want to see OOM then either:

- You use small object `new Object()` + small heap size like `Xmx64`
- You create some heavy objects like Calendar (`objects.add(Calendar.getInstance());`) + `Xmx512`

With `new Object()` + `Xmx512`, you will have to wait for very long time to get OOM.

On your unreachable code error, I think you have already figured out that you were having parenthesis problem, if you do like below then you will not get that compilation error, but if you put any statement after WHILE loop then you will get that error.

```
    while (true){
        objects.add(Calendar.getInstance());
        System.out.println(objects);
    }
```

Comment: I modified the code a little and it took me 11420584 Objects to spawn the error, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The compiler might eliminate this code as it is considered dead code and not execute it at all.

Try introducing side effects like a print statement **inside** the loop.

Comment: well, my idea was to add some actions with these objects later in the loop, but the code's unreachable for some reason

Answer (score 0):

Fairly easy (executed from within the IntelliJ IDEA):

```
public class Foo {

    public static void main(String[] argv) throws IllegalAccessException {

        Collection<byte[]> data = new ArrayList<>();
        for (;;) {
            data.add(new byte[1000]);
        }

    }
}
```

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
>       at Foo.main(Foo.java:15)
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: Yeah, but that's not exactly what I want. Obviously, there won't be enough contiguous space for arrays of such size, but for small objects it doesn't seem to work that way

Comment: Just tried it with 1000 same effect, and 1Kb is not a massively big object, is it?

Comment: Compared to size of a single Object it's quite big, actually

Comment: You did not specify in your question that it must be `new Object()`, which is quite a useless construct if not optimized away all together. What is that you want to achieve? You want to check recovery after OOME, this should be more than good enough.

Comment: I want to understand why the error isn't thrown in this particular case

Comment: But you are likely to have all possible side effects with a list of billion entries. Do you know how the GC will behave if it needs to investigate the state of the VM which contains that number of objects, in a linked list (so it would need to iterate it to find it if anything can be collected). You would not be testing OOME, you would be testing if JVM can cope with that number of objects

Comment: the thing is if I set -Xmx1024m, then it behaves the same way, i.e. goes up to ~1000m and then stops consuming